# Why does a locally allocated variable in a closure works differently when allocated outside?

Tags: go, closures, channel, goroutine

I have a closure in a function like this:

```golang
func permutate(ch chan []int, numbers []int, r int) {
    // ... see the full program below
    perm := make([]int, r, r)
    nextPerm := func() []int {
        for i, ind := range indices[:r] {
            perm[i] = numbers[ind]
        }
        return perm
    }
    // later writing to ch in two places:
    // ch <- nextPerm()  
    // ...
}
```

This works differently when I allocate the `perm` variable inside the closure:

```golang
func permutate(ch chan []int, numbers []int, r int) {
    // ...
    nextPerm := func() []int {
        perm := make([]int, r, r)
        for i, ind := range indices[:r] {
            perm[i] = numbers[ind]
        }
        return perm
    }
    // ...
}
```

I don't understand why. What's the difference between the two variations?
I only run `permutate` in exactly one goroutine, so writing to the channel should happen in a serial manner, so no two goroutines should modify the `perm` variable at once.
I tried to debug what is happening, but I guess it's a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) because during the debugging, the race condition will not happen, so I guess it has something to do with the scheduling of goroutines.

Here is the full program (with the global `perm` variable):

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func IterPermutations(numbers []int, r int) <-chan []int {
    if r > len(numbers) {
        err := errors.New("r cannot be bigger than the length of numbers")
        panic(err)
    }

    ch := make(chan []int)
    go func() {
        defer close(ch)
        permutate(ch, numbers, r)
    }()
    return ch
}

// an implementation similar to Python standard library itertools.permutations:
// https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations
func permutate(ch chan []int, numbers []int, r int) {
    n := len(numbers)

    if r < 0 {
        r = n
    }

    indices := make([]int, n, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        indices[i] = i
    }

    cycles := make([]int, r, r)
    for i := 0; i < r; i++ {
        cycles[i] = n - i
    }

    perm := make([]int, r, r)
    nextPerm := func() []int {
        for i, ind := range indices[:r] {
            perm[i] = numbers[ind]
        }
        return perm
    }

    ch <- nextPerm()

    if n < 2 {
        return
    }

    var tmp []int
    var j int

    for i := r - 1; i > -1; i-- {
        cycles[i] -= 1
        if cycles[i] == 0 {
            tmp = append(indices[i+1:], indices[i])
            indices = append(indices[:i], tmp...)
            cycles[i] = n - i
        } else {
            j = len(indices) - cycles[i]
            indices[i], indices[j] = indices[j], indices[i]
            ch <- nextPerm()
            i = r // start over the cycle
            // i-- will apply, so i will be r-1 at the start of the next cycle
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    for perm := range IterPermutations(phaseSettings, 3) {
        fmt.Println(perm)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first example, all slices returned from the function share the same backing array.   Run the application with the [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector).

Comment: I run with very simple testcases (0, 1, and 2 elements) but there is no race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data race. When you declare `perm` outside of the closure, the closure re-uses `perm` everytime it is called and modifies it.

After main goroutine receives the slice over the channel, the `permutate` goroutine can keep running and calls the next `nextPerm()` - which modifies the slice, as explained. This may or may not happen before the main goroutine use it (or even happen in middle of something), which is a data race. So `fmt.Println(perm)` may print the next iter of permutation or the right one (or in rare case, a mix-up of two).

When you declare `perm` inside of the closure, it is a new variable and has new allocation of underlying arrays each time the closure is called. So nothing is shared, and no data is raced on.

Note: The race detector of Go might be unable to detect a data race everytime - since data race may simply not happen everytime. To read more on the race detecter, see https://blog.golang.org/race-detector and https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerAlgorithm .